# Why does my my door have odd circular lighting effect on it?

Tags: rendering, lighting

All of my other meshes have normal lighting on then but when it comes to my shower door it creates this odd circular effect that I just can't seem to remove.

[image]

The door is just a cube, however when I duplicate the single front face of the cube as shown here the lighting looks normal. When I extend the face to make a cube it adds that circular effect.

[image]

I haven't applied any materials to any of these objects yet so I'm not quite sure what is going on here.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information detailing how you set up your project or your materials.

Comment: Probably you have inverted normals on this object, but I'm not sure as this looks like render from Blender Internal and I don't know it at all.

Comment: Do you accidentally have a phong shader attached to doors?

Comment: What is a phong shader?

Comment: I have tried recalculating the normals but it is the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry I'm a little new to this. I tried creating a cube with the exact dimensions and it turned out fine. I've discovered that the lighting behaves in this way if you changed the shading here to 'Smooth' as opposed to 'flat'.

[image]